# Why does export default App; in my App.tsx file compile down to exports.default = App; in the App.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Working in React with a typescript template.

exports.default = App; doesn't compile on the browser, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined". How do I stop this behaviour?

Comment: Hi! can you share the minimal code to reproduce the issue? I would be happy to help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm learning Typescript/React with a Youtube video. When I finish my App.tsx file with the line 'export default App;', it compiles down to 'exports.default = App;' in the App.js file. exports.default = App crashes the web page.